# Using AWS Lambda Java function to read data from Self Managed Kafka Cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I have successfully implemented
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/

But my issue is I want to write the code in Java instead of NodeJs.
The payload returned is shown below. How do I extract the value which is Base64 encoded ?

Thanks,
Anirban

```
{
    "eventSource": "SelfManagedKafka",
    "bootstrapServers": "sp-dev-broker-0.stre.nsawsdev.mycompany.com:9093",
    "records": {
        "lambda_test-0": [
            {
                "topic": "lambda_test",
                "partition": 0,
                "offset": 0,
                "timestamp": 1660073644797,
                "timestampType": "CREATE_TIME",
                "value": "eyJOYW1lIjogIkFuaXJiYW4gQmlzd2FzIn0=",
                "headers": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My class looks like this and I see the the Lambda getting invoked when I publish data on topic.

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<KafkaEvent, String> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(KafkaEvent event, Context context) {

        log.info("Lambda function is invoked:" +event.getRecords().values().toString());
        return null;


    }
}
```

AWS Lambda Cloudatch log shows this

```
Lambda function is invoked:[[KafkaEvent.KafkaEventRecord(topic=lambda_test, partition=0, offset=0, timestamp=1660073644797, timestampType=CREATE_TIME, key=null, value=eyJOYW1lIjogIkFuaXJiYW4gQmlzd2FzIn0=)]]
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out.


public class App implements RequestHandler<KafkaEvent, String> {

 private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

 @Override
 public String handleRequest(KafkaEvent event, Context context) {


  for( Map.Entry<String, List<KafkaEvent.KafkaEventRecord>> record : event.getRecords().entrySet()) {
   for (KafkaEvent.KafkaEventRecord record2 : record.getValue()) {

    log.info("Value is :" + new String((Base64.getDecoder().decode(record2.getValue()))));
   }

  }
  return null;
 }
}

Comment: Put your code below as an answer, not a comment